# Should a CNN generalize to arbitrary positions in the data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, signal-processing

I have trained a CNN on one dimensional data that is the power spectral density (PSD) of a $N$ different classes of signals ($N=4$). Each of the $N$ signals has a different spectral shape (not shown here). For illustrative purposes, the plots shown below are from the same signal class. The idea is to treat this as an image classification problem.

The model performs exceptionally well when the training data has all the examples centered around the same frequency (i.e., within a few hundred Hertz): [image: All training examples centered on or around 0 Hz]

The CNN fails to properly classify new examples that are outside the frequency range of the training data:

[image: Invalid classification, new data outside frequency range of trained data]

**Model Details and Assumptions:**

The CNN model is implemented in PyTorch using the following layers:

```
    model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=128, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=16, stride=2),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(257664, n_classes)
    )
```

The optimizer is `torch.optim.Adam`. Batch size has been varied from 8 to 128, epochs varied from 10 to 50. The input data is normalized to $[0,1]$. Training examples varied from [2000, 8000], where 20% are used for validation and 20% are used for test.
I have also tried adding additional convolutional layers, varying the kernal sizes, neurons, layers, etc.

**Questions:**

1. Shouldn't the CNN model generalize such that new examples that are not within the same frequency range (i.e., centered around the middle) should be identified as the correct class?
2. Are there other steps I need to take, whether in the model or training data?

Comment: *"I have trained a CNN..."* what did you make the CNN train for? To recognize the class of a signal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CNN does not automatically need to generalize to arbitrary translations. I can see 2 possibilities that allow a CNN to generalise to arbitrary translations

- **Data augmentation**

  Image classification models are unaware of variations that may occur in new data that where not present in previous data.

  If you trained a model to recognize shapes but always around a specific coordinate, then it might bake that location into the model. It will not recognize the shape independently from the location, and instead it will be more something like recognizing the values at specific locations. E.g. it learns that if there is a step function around the specific locations $ \pm 1000 Hz$ then it is of the class in your example.

  When you feed the model during the training phase multiple variations of the data (you can use the same data, and apply some transformations) then the model will be able to adapt to those potential variations. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=data+augmentation
- **Network architecture**

  You can have a convolutional neural networks be automatically translation invariant by adding a (global) pooling layer after the first convolutional layers in the model (without having layers before that which may filter the spatial information in the data before or after the convolution, although they might be neccesary for making up for information that gets lost by having a global pooling layer).

---

I see now that I missed your architecture description. You have no global pooling, and therefore the network is not automatically translation invariant.

I don't believe that more convolution layers are really neccesary (as you describe in your own answer) if the model already works when you have samples without translation. What you need is a global pooling layer. (Potentially you can place this after more than one convolution layers, but those additional layers do not create translation invariance)

The actual shapes in your signal classes may help to figure out a design (whether to use more layers or not). You should be able to figure out how more or less how the network connects the layers (or fails to connect) and how it recognizis the different classes.

Currently it seems like you have a single convolution with a filter of size 128, that gets filtered with a sliding window of maxPooling and finally a linear model determines the classes. That final linear model will only train to recognize the output of the kernel in the particular places that occur in the training. When the signal pattern occurs somewhere else at a different place, then there is no reason why the trained model should be recognising this. It are different neurons that become activated (relating to the kernel during convolution getting some high value in a different place) and your model did not learn to connect to those different neurons.

In short the image below is how I see this

- Input signal
- Several kernels (whose shape you train) convert this into a convolved signal. E.g. a filter like $1\cdot x_{k-2} + 1 \cdot x_{k-1} + 0\cdot x_{k} -1 \cdot x_{k+1} - 1\cdot k_{k+2}$ will turn the signal into positive and negative spikes whenever there is a step function.
- You only keep the positive part.
- Then you fit a linear model to predict the classes. But this model will only create strong links to the places where the training signal has often a spike in the convolved signal. There is no reason why the training should create response to spikes in different places.

[image]

Comment: I would expect a properly designed CNN to learn the translation of the training data without explicitly providing all the examples of said translations. I am investigating the model architecture and will report back.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 the network is naive to any concepts that we as trainers (who have had years of training) might understand. Our expectations about the tricks that a network should be able to learn can be false.

Comment: You are correct. I tried one conv layer followed by a global pooling operation and that provided translation invariance. I’ll update my answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

No, it has been demonstrated how CNNs with Relus fail to generalize outside of the training domain, more specifically, it fails to classify samples with high confidence. See [Why relu networks yield high-confidence predictions far away from the training data and how to mitigate the problem](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Hein_Why_ReLU_Networks_Yield_High-Confidence_Predictions_Far_Away_From_the_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf).

The idea is that the output space of a CNN with relus is piecewise (roughly speaking a bunch of hyperplanes that define the regions associated with each class in the case of classification). The authors show that it is always possible to find for (almost) all directions an input z far away from the training data which is assigned some label with high confidence.

Also, as a consequence of the theorem, they show that techniques like introducing a rejection option, or manipulating the logits in some form cannot help solve this issue.

They propose a adversarial training technique which aims at enforcing the network to produce outputs with lower confidence for out-of-distribution inputs.

I do not suggest that this is necessarily the solution to your problem. It might also be possible to improve your results with appropriate data augmentation or preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The short version is:

1. Improve model architecture. Larger strides for the large kernal sizes for this particular case.
2. Include global pooling at final layer
3. More conv layers (use 3-4) with RELU and max pooling if model does not perform well before offsets are introduced
4. For best performance, train with data that includes off centered offsets, but not necessarily required if model is properly designed

See answer posted here and the comments for additional details:

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38649/should-a-cnn-generalize-to-arbitrary-positions-in-the-data

Comment: Yes, it is possible to be shift invariant, but the answer to 'should it be?' is no. Shift invariance is automatically obtained with a *first* convolutional layer plus a global pooling (not the last layer as you state, as the earlier layers may create a local sensitivity that a later global pooling cannot undo).

Comment: I tried this and yes you are in fact correct. I updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: I am still not sure how this question answers the question "Should a CNN generalize to arbitrary positions in the data?". The answer is that it shouldn't be neccesarily the case. Your point 2 is a sufficient condition (although pooling at the very end may not always work when layers before it filter spatial information) and point 4 may work as well. But points 1 and 3 are improvements that can be made to networks that do not have to do with the question.

Comment: Would a better question be, "How can a CNN be extended to generalize to arbitrary positions in the data?". It seems like we're getting caught up on semantics, but if a clearer question should be asked, I am happy to make that change

Comment: Ablation studies examine the consequences of removing components of a model and assessing what, if any, effect it has on the model’s performance. This answer proposes a model that is more complex than necessary. Long story short, shouldn’t we prefer the simplest model that solves a problem to our desired level of precision?

Comment: Disagree that this answer proposes a more complex model than necessary. What part of the answer suggests that? #3 is a caveated step. But yes, simple models are better than more complex models.

Comment: If we give up 3 and 4, then your answer doesn't add anything beyond what Sextus' answer does -- or, in the alternative, the steps that it does add don't solve the problem that's stated in your question.

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought he updated his answer after I posted mine to include the discussion on global pooling? #4 is required for classification of signals that are partially cut off, so it can't be ignored.

Comment: This edit from Jan 10 is the first mention of pooling that I find. https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/601478/2 On the other hand, this answer is from Jan 15 or 16 (it just says "Yesterday" right now).

Comment: Gotcha. What would you like me to do? I don't see specifics about #1 in his answer, nor do I see #3 and #4. I could either reword my question or we can leave things as they are. The goal is for this post to be helpful for any future visitors of this question and we are accomplishing that.

Comment: Large kernels aren't needed to solve this problem, either. As an example, a kernel $[+1,-1]$ (or similar) will yield $x_i - x_{i-1}$ (or similar), which will look like a spike for this problem because the plots show a jump from one time step to the next (as best I can tell from the plots). The global pool will identify the spike. At the core, I'm struggling to see how this answer is helpful to future readers, because it contains suggestions which are, at best, incidental to solving the stated task, mixed in with a single suggestion which is useful.

Comment: The plots in the original post were representative and not intended to describe all possible classes. As such, the kernel described will work on the step function data, but doesn’t generalize for a wide range of shapes.

Comment: The title of the post is "Should a CNN generalize to arbitrary positions in the data?" and the answer is "It can if you use a CNN layer, then a pooling layer." The examples in the post are sufficient as a test case for the question and answers. It's all well and good to seek to generalize the result of the answer to the titular question, but that seems a bit afield from the focus of the question. From another view, essentially every NN task has an aspect which is addressed by "add more parameters," either as layers or weights within layers.